# How to configure OpenSSL on the QT

Tags: c++, windows, qt, openssl, qnetworkrequest

How can I make my *QwebView/QNetWorkRequest* work with *SSL*?

QT return this errors (is clear that the error occurs because I did not configure SSL in my application):

> QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf
>   QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_conf
>   QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_conf

I am use Qt 5.1.1 for Windows 32-bit (MinGW 4.8, OpenGL) - my window is 64bit

I'll be honest, I have no idea where to start.
I searched but have not found anywhere that shows how trabalar SSL with *QNetWorkRequest*.

I install openSslWin32 (my Windows is 64bit, but my application is 32bit), I try this:

**pro file:**

```
LIBS += -LC:/OpenSSL-Win32/lib -lubsec
INCLUDEPATH += C:/OpenSSL-Win32/include
```

**cpp file:**

```
#include <openssl/aes.h>
```

But continues to show errors.

I know it is missing something, but do not know what exactly, forgive me I'm beginner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am install OpenSSL 32bit, is now working.

**Download precompiled for Windows:**

http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

Downloads:

- Win32: http://slproweb.com/download/Win32OpenSSL_Light-1_0_2j.exe
- Win64: http://slproweb.com/download/Win64OpenSSL_Light-1_0_2j.exe

After install copy DLLs (from `C:\OpenSSL-Win32` or `C:\OpenSSL-Win64`, depends on whether you will compile with Qt 32bit or Qt 64bit) for `release` or `debug` project folder:

- libeay32.dll
- libssl32.dll
- ssleay32.dll

> Note: No need to add anything to "LIBS +="

Answer (score 2):

You may be missing a bunch of libraries.

Go into C:/OpenSSL-Win32/lib and find out which 32 bit libraries are present and add them all to your
link line,

ie if libXYZ.a is present in the directory add -lXYZ to your LIBS += statement.